# Python threading: How to repeat calling a thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, wxpython, python-multithreading

I wanted the long-running script to keep monitoring the web data. So I do a recursion inside the thread. The code is like,

```
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, window):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.window = window
        self.timeToQuit = threading.Event()
        self.timeToQuit.clear()

    def stop(self):
        self.timeToQuit.set()

    def run(self):

        # the script goes here

        time.sleep(5)
        self.run()
```

But the problem is that it raised a error, `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Is there another way to repeat calling the worker thread? BTW I do the GUI by wxPython. Thanks!

Comment: you are recusevly run the same `self.run()` function. In `run(self)` method you should run the desired job. e.g.: `monitoring_function(web='my_web')` instead of `self.run()`.

Comment: instead of running a new thread every time..why don't add while loop inside the run method which keep it running